# using OWLreasoner javascript library, trouble loading ontology

Tags: javascript, ontology, owl

I am trying to load an ontology using this library https://code.google.com/p/owlreasoner/.

I am using the same method shown(link) to load an `.owl` file with the `url` parser.

```
var url = "http://www.co-ode.org/ontologies/pizza/2005/05/16/pizza.owl";        
var ontology = jsw.owl.xml.parseUrl(url);       
var size = ontology.getSize();
console.log(ontology)   
console.log(url)
console.log(size)
```

the logs return the following:
 log(url)

```
http://www.co-ode.org/ontologies/pizza/2005/05/16/pizza.owl
```

log(ontology)

```
jsw.owl.Ontology {entities: Object, axioms: Array[0], prefixes: Object, nextEntityNos: Object, entityCount: Object…}
axioms: Array[0]
entities: Object
entityCount: Object
nextEntityNos: Object
prefixes: Object
__proto__: Object
```

log(size)

```
0
```

I am not getting any errors, it just seems to result in an object with an empty array instead of an array that is populated with my ontology.

any help would be great, 
cheers!

Comment: UPDATE: I went into the library functions and I think I have a work around, as the ontology is loading, but I am now having trouble querying the ontology. This could well be due to me editing the library, but I doubt it. Does anybody know of any other good alternatives for manipulating and querying OWL ontologies?

Comment: The OWL-API is a very good alternative to manipulate and create ontologies, yet it's written in Java and it might differ from your requirements.

Comment: thanks loopasm, I have looked into that and it looks good. I was hoping for a library of similar standard in javascript as it will save a lot of work! I have been looking for ages and trying different ones, might have to bite the bullet and do it!

Comment: What are you doing exactly with OWL in the client side? Usually people process it on the server side, because it often requires a lot of computing power (reasoning, large data set, etc...)

Comment: I am implementing a content management system, so users can easily update an ontology, being able to add/remove classes and properties (possibly in the future instances), similar to protege but hopefully simplified and more restricted so a non-tech user could use it.  I am new to all types of programming and have kind of been thrown in at the deep end here haha! Would you recommend manipulating the `.owl` file server side? thanks for the help.

Comment: Ontologies are used in various contexts, people are still figuring out what's the best. For instance with schema.org in order to annotate the content of the web for search engines. You can also use an ontology instead/with a database on the server side to improve the interoperability/semantics of your application. It really depends what you want to do! You could also look at http://protegewiki.stanford.edu/wiki/WebProtege for your use-case.

Comment: thanks for your help loopasm, will look into webProtege, looks interesting!